# How to use single dbml file with different database

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I am using LinqToSql. I have different databases for my application(Just database name is different).
I pick url value and then use database according to that.

Problem is that there is a single .dbml file, there is one constructor where connection string is picked from web.config file.
But I need to use different databases according to query string. 
Can we use single dbml file with more than 1 databases and how?

Is there possible solution for this?

Comment: As you'll need one database at a time, you can change database name in connection string object at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change database name in the connection string at runtime.
Just create context object with new connection string parameter and use it for queries.

```
DataContext context = new DataContext (newConnectionString);
```